# Google Cloud: Compute VM Instances

Tags: root, google-compute-engine

How do I get root access to my Google VM instance, and also how can I log into my VM Instance from my PC with a SSH client such as putty?

I would also like to add that I have tried to do sudo for things that need root access to do those things, such as yum or wget. But it does not allow me to do sudo, it asks me for the root password but I do not know how, or where I would be able to get the root password.

Comment: Try read the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances#sshing). Also this belongs on [superuser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 52):

You can become root via `sudo su`. No password is required.

Comment: I am loginning in through ssh and it requires password

Answer (score 17):

### How do I use `sudo` to execute commands as root?

*(splitting this off from [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26950473/3618671) since there are multiple questions within this post)*

Once you connect to your GCE VM using PuTTY or `gcloud compute instances ssh` or even clicking on the "SSH" button on the Developers Console next to the instance, you should be able to use the `sudo` command. Note that you shouldn't be using the `su` command to become root, just run:

```
sudo [command]
```

and it should not prompt you for a password.

If you want to get a root shell to run several commands as root and you want to avoid prefixing all commands with `sudo`, run:

```
sudo su -
```

If you're still having issues, please post a new question with the exact command you're running and the output that you see.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to connect your gce (google-cloud) server with putty using root, here is the flow:

use puttygen to generate two ppk files:

1. for your gce-default-user
2. for root

do the followings on putty (replace gce-default-user with your gce username):

Putty->session->Connection->data->Auto-login username: gce-default-user

Putty->session->Connection->SSH->Auth->Private-key for authentication: gce-default-user.ppk

Then connect to server using your gce-default-user

make the following changes in sshd_config

sudo su

nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

PermitRootLogin yes

UsePAM no

Save+exit

service sshd restart

Putty->session->Connection->data->Auto-login username: root

Putty->session->Connection->SSH->Auth->Private-key for authentication: root-gce.ppk

Now ou can login to root via putty.

**If you need to use eclipse remote system and log-in as root:**

Eclipse->windows->preferences->General->network Connection->SSH2->private-keys:
root-gce.ppk

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo su root <enter key>
```

No password required :)

Comment: I get ```We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
[sudo] password for my-user-name```

Answer (score 2):

Please try `sudo su -` on GCE.
By default on GCE, there is no password required to `sudo` (do as a substitute user). The `-` argument to `su` (substitute user) further simulates a full login, taking the target user (the default user for both is root) configured login shell and its profile scripts to set new environment parameters. You'll at least notice the prompt change from ending in `$` to `#` in any case.

Answer (score 1):

### How do I connect to my GCE instance using PuTTY?

*(splitting this off from [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26950482/3618671) since there are multiple questions within this post)*

Take a look at [setting up ssh keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/console#sshkeys) in the GCE documentation which shows how to do it; here's the summary but read the doc for additional notes:

> 1. Generate your keys using [ssh-keygen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) or [PuTTYgen](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_puttygen) for Windows, if you haven't already.
> 2. Copy the contents of your public key. If you just generated this key, it can probably be found in a file named `id_rsa.pub`.
> 3. [Log in](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/console#access) to the Developers Console.
> 4. In the navigation, **Compute->Compute Engine->Metadata**.
> 5. Click the **SSH Keys** tab.
> 6. Click the **Edit** button.
> 7. In the empty input box at the bottom of the list, enter the corresponding public key, in the following format:
>      
>      `<protocol> <public-key> username@example.com`
>      
>      This makes your public key automatically available to all of your instances in that project. To add multiple keys, list each key on a new line.
> 8. Click **Done** to save your changes.
>      
>      It can take several minutes before the key is inserted into the instance. Try connecting with ssh to your instance. If it is successful, your key has been propagated to the instance.

Answer (score 1):

JUST GOT TO CLOUD SHELL BY CLICKING SSH

AND FOLLOW PASSWORD CHANGE COMMAND FOR ROOT USER USING SUDO :)

sudo passwd

and it will change the root password :)

then to becom root use command

su

type your password and become a root :)

Comment: Google Compute Engine VMs provide passwordless `sudo` so you should not create a password for the root user as that will make it *less* secure. Just use `sudo su -` to become root, do NOT set a root password (it will likely get hacked remotely with a dictionary attack; you are better off using certificates for authentication).

Comment: @MishaBrukman how to remove password if I already setup a root password?

Comment: @RahulSharma — if this is Ubuntu, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/20453/280294). Before you do that, make sure you have `sudo` properly configured, so that you don't break your installation.