# Why can I ask for a password when using the su command problem when using GCE?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am awkward because I am trying a translation tool, but please forgive me

As a problem su command is no longer available

I think that the same account was used as the cause and that access was done simultaneously from different terminals

Please tell me how to resolve

Comment: The question is a bit unclear however, I think the following [community post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835235/google-cloud-compute-vm-instances) should be helpful in this case. You may also try enabling [OSLogin](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#enable_oslogin) as suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today.  You need to enable oslogin by adding the necessary meta data to your Instance (likely your project as well).

Instructions below.  Solved it for me.  Hope it helps

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#enable_oslogin

To set enable-oslogin in project-wide metadata so that it applies to all of the instances **in your project**:

Go to the Metadata page.
Click Edit.
Add a metadata entry where the key is **enable-oslogin** and the value is TRUE. Alternatively, set the value to FALSE to disable the feature.

Click Save to apply the changes.

To Set **enable-oslogin** in metadata of an **existing instance**:

Go to the VM instances page.
Click the name of the instance on which you want to set the metadata value.
At the top of the instance details page, click Edit to edit the instance settings.
Under Custom metadata, add a metadata entry where the key is **enable-oslogin** and the value is TRUE. Alternatively, set the value to FALSE to exclude the instance from the feature.
At the bottom of the instance details page, click Save to apply your changes to the instance.

To Set **enable-oslogin** in instance metadata when you **create an instance**:

In the GCP Console, go to the VM Instances page.

Click Create instance.
On the Create a new instance page, fill in the desired properties for your instance.
In the Metadata section, add a metadata entry where the key is **enable-oslogin** and the value is TRUE. Alternatively, set the value to FALSE to exclude the instance from the feature.
Click Create to create the instance.

Comment: Please, provide a command or a step-by-step when possible, links may change.